# Joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have 3 tables STUDENT, STUDENT_GPA, STUDENT_ATTENDANCE as below

```
STUDENT
--------
STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME
-----------------------
1          A
2          B
3          C
4          D
5          E

SUBJECTS
--------
STUDENT_ID  GPA UPDATE_FLG
---------------------------
2           8     Y
4           7     Y
5           8     N


STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
------------------
STUDENT_ID  ATTENDANCE  UPDATE_FLG
----------------------------------
3           92           Y


Output should be

STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME GPA    ATTENDANCE
--------------------------------------
2           B           8      NULL
3           C           NULL   92
4           D           7      NULL
```

I tried the below query, but it is not working correctly. It is missing rows from either of tables

```
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID,
       S.STUDENT_NAME,
       SD.GPA,
       SA.ATTENDANCE
FROM STUDENT S
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_GPA SD ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SD.STUDENT_ID
                                   AND SD.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ATTENDANCE SA ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SA.STUDENT_ID
                                          AND SA.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, it is not very clear from your question as to what resultset you need, however, looks like you want to select the data for those students whose GPA is updated or whose attendance is updated and you want to ignore all other records.

Based on this understanding, below query gives you the expected resultset.

```
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_NAME, SD.GPA, SA.ATTENDANCE 
FROM STUDENT S LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_GPA SD ON 
(S.STUDENT_ID=SD.STUDENT_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ATTENDANCE SA ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SA.STUDENT_ID)
WHERE SA.UPDATE_FLG = 'Y' OR SD.UPDATE_FLG = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID,
       S.STUDENT_NAME,
       SD.GPA,
       SA.ATTENDANCE
FROM STUDENT S
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_GPA SD ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SD.STUDENT_ID
                                   AND SD.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ATTENDANCE SA ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SA.STUDENT_ID
                                          AND SA.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
UNION
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID,
       S.STUDENT_NAME,
       SD.GPA,
       SA.ATTENDANCE
FROM STUDENT S
RIGHT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_GPA SD ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SD.STUDENT_ID
                                    AND SD.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
RIGHT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_ATTENDANCE SA ON (S.STUDENT_ID=SA.STUDENT_ID
                                           AND SA.UPDATE_FLG='Y')
```

Comment: So, if I am going to have 5 tables joined, then I have to UNION all the 'Select' same way?

Comment: Yes but that would take alot of time
you can also do
`SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_NAME, SD.GPA, SA.ATTENDANCE 
FROM STUDENT S ,STUDENT_GPA SD,STUDENT_ATTENDANCE SA
where S.STUDENT_ID=SD.STUDENT_ID
and S.STUDENT_ID=SA.STUDENT_I`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select *
from (
  select s.student_id, s.student_name,
    max(case when sub.update_flag = 'Y' then sub.gpa end) gpa,
    max(case when att.update_flag = 'Y' then att.attendance end) attendance
  from student s 
    left join subjects sub on s.student_id = sub.student_id 
    left join student_attendance att on s.student_id = att.student_id
  group by s.student_id, s.student_name
  ) t
where gpa is not null or attendance is not null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0d56a/1)